# Which way to use send messages into topic using azure function?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I found two ways to send messages into service bus topic from azure function.

one is using output -

```
[FunctionName("ServiceBusOutput")]
[return: ServiceBus("myqueue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]
public static string ServiceBusOutput([HttpTrigger] dynamic input, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# function processed: {input.Text}");
    return input.Text;
}
```

Another is using code -

```
const string ServiceBusConnectionString = "string";
const string TopicName = "topicName";
static ITopicClient topicClient;
topicClient = new TopicClient(ServiceBusConnectionString, TopicName);
string messageBody = "Test";
var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageBody));
await topicClient.SendAsync(message);
```

> I'm not getting which one we should use and when?
>
> 1. if we use `Output` how to pass queue name `myqueue` as a variable
>      so that in code we can assign it.
> 2. if i have array how can we return one by one message to output
>      return which will send one by one message to queue ?

Answer (score 2):

Full examples from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#output---example). For instance, how to write multiple messages, using the `ICollector`

```
public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log, [ServiceBus("myqueue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] ICollector<string> outputSbQueue)
{
    string message = $"Service Bus queue messages created at: {DateTime.Now}";
    log.LogInformation(message); 
    outputSbQueue.Add("1 " + message);
    outputSbQueue.Add("2 " + message);
}
```

As far as I know the first version, using `return` does not work if you have any async calls inside your Function. The version using the collector can also work in async Functions but simply using an `IAsyncCollector` instead.

Comment: what about myqueue if i want to pass it from my code i mean can i set it in variable ? so that i will change it on condition ?

Comment: Is it using `[return: ServiceBus(...)]` on the method and `[ServiceBus(...)]` on the parameter the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. if we use `Output` how to pass queue name `myqueue` as a variable
>      so that in code we can assign it.

For this you can use `Imperative Binding`.Imperative binding is useful when binding parameters need to be computed at runtime rather than design time. More reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#binding-at-runtime)

Example:

```
public static async Task ServiceBusBinderTest(
 string message,
 int numMessages,
 Binder binder) {
 var attribute = new ServiceBusAttribute(BinderQueueName) {
  EntityType = EntityType.Queue
 };
 var collector = await binder.BindAsync < IAsyncCollector < string >> (attribute);

 for (int i = 0; i < numMessages; i++) {
  await collector.AddAsync(message + i);
 }

 await collector.FlushAsync();
}
```

> if i have array how can we return one by one message to output return which will send one by one message to queue ?

You can configure the `OnMessageOptions` instance with decreasing your `MaxConcurrentCalls`

```
OnMessageOptions options = new OnMessageOptions();
options.AutoComplete = false;
options.MaxConcurrentCalls = 5;
```